# filter mail by real recipient

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have a site, say `example.org`. All mail to addresses like `*@example.org` is redirected to one account.

I use gmail to get all mail from this account.
I use few filters like `to: concreteadress@example.org` to tag them.

The problem is: when somebody sent mail

```
from sender@server
to: sender@server
bcc: hidden list, concreteadress@example.org, somebody else
```

my filters isn't applied. How do I change my filter to check real recipient(how did I get it?) instead of `to` field?

Comment: why don't you use `bcc`?

Comment: @Jacob Jan Tuinstra `bcc:me` or `bcc:my-gmail@gmail.com` seems to work fine, but `bcc: concreteadress@example.org` doesn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `deliveredto:` search keyword.

From [Google support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190):

> Search for messages within a particular email address in the Delivered-To line of the message header
>
> Example: deliveredto:username@gmail.com
>   Meaning: Any message with username@gmail.com in the Delivered-To: field of the message header (which can help you find messages forwarded from another account or ones sent to an alias).

So, searching for (or using a filter with) `deliveredto: concreteadress@example.org` should give you what you need.

Comment: When I search `deliveredto: concreteadress@example.org` I don't find any result. If I click to show original I see `Delivered-To: my-gmail-account@gmail.com` as first nonempty line.